# Why is calling await completing the parent Task prematurely?

Tags: c#, .net, winrt-xaml, async-await

I'm trying to create a control that exposes a `DoLoading` event that consumers can subscribe to in order to perform loading operations. For convenience, event handlers should be called from the UI thread allowing consumers to update the UI at will, but they will also be able to use async/await to perform long-running tasks without blocking the UI thread.

For this, I have declared the following delegate:

```
public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

That allows consumers to subscribe to the event:

```
public event AsyncEventHandler<bool> DoLoading;
```

The idea is that consumers will subscribe to the event as so (this line is executed in the UI thread):

```
loader.DoLoading += async (s, e) =>
            {
                for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    loader.Text = i.ToString(); // UI update
                    await Task.Delay(1000); // long-running task doesn't block UI
                }
            };
```

At an appropriate point in time, I'm getting a `TaskScheduler` for the UI thread and storing it in `_uiScheduler`.

The event is triggered when appropriate by the `loader` with the following line (this happens in a random thread):

```
this.PerformLoadingActionAsync().ContinueWith(
            _ =>
            {
                // Other operations that must happen on UI thread
            },
            _uiScheduler);
```

Notice that this line is not called from the UI thread but needs to update the UI when loading is completed, so I'm using `ContinueWith` to execute code on the UI task scheduler when the loading task completes.

I've tried several variations of the following methods, none of which have worked, so here's where I'm at:

```
private async Task<Task> PerformLoadingActionAsync()
{
    TaskFactory uiFactory = new TaskFactory(_uiScheduler);

    // Trigger event on the UI thread and await its execution
    Task evenHandlerTask = await uiFactory.StartNew(async () => await this.OnDoLoading(_mustLoadPreviousRunningState));

    // This can be ignored for now as it completes immediately
    Task commandTask = Task.Run(() => this.ExecuteCommand());

    return Task.WhenAll(evenHandlerTask, commandTask);
}

private async Task OnDoLoading(bool mustLoadPreviousRunningState)
{
    var handler = this.DoLoading;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        await handler(this, mustLoadPreviousRunningState);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm starting two tasks and expect my `ContinueWith` from before to execute one *all* of them complete.

The `commandTask` completes immediately, so it can be ignored for the moment. The `eventHandlerTask`, as I see it, should only complete one the event handler completes, given that I'm awaiting the call to the method that calls the event handler and I'm awaiting the event handler itself.

However, what's actually happening, is that the tasks are being completed as soon as the line `await Task.Delay(1000)` in my event handler is executed.

Why is this and how can I get the behaviour I expect?

Comment: Doesn't  your `await uiFactory.StartNew(async () => await this.OnDoLoading(_mustLoadPreviousRunningState));` produce compilation errors?

Comment: @Геннадий-Ванин I don't see any reason why it should.

Comment: Actually, I had figured out the problem shortly after I wrote the question, but I was looking forward to getting some feedback on my approach and svick and Stephen have both written great answers for which I thank them a lot. As soon as I get the chance to read them thoroughly I'll mark one of them as an answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You correctly realized that `StartNew()` returns `Task<Task>` in this case, and you care about the inner `Task` (though I'm not sure why are you waiting for the outer `Task` before starting `commandTask`).

But then you return `Task<Task>` and ignore the inner `Task`. What you should do is to use `await` instead of `return` and change the return type of `PerformLoadingActionAsync()` to just `Task`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(evenHandlerTask, commandTask);
```

Few more notes:

1. Using event handlers this way is quite dangerous, because you care about the `Task` returned from the handler, but if there are more handlers, only the last `Task` will be returned if you raise the event normally. If you really want to do this, you should call [`GetInvocationList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx), which lets you invoke and `await` each handler separately:

   ```
   private async Task OnDoLoading(bool mustLoadPreviousRunningState)
   {
       var handler = this.DoLoading;

       if (handler != null)
       {
           var handlers = handler.GetInvocationList();

           foreach (AsyncEventHandler<bool> innerHandler in handlers)
           {
               await innerHandler(this, mustLoadPreviousRunningState);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   If you know that you'll never have more than one handler, you could use a delegate property that can be directly set instead of an event.
2. If you have an `async` method or lambda that has the only `await` just before its `return` (and no `finally`s), then you don't need to make it `async`, just return the `Task` directly:

   ```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.OnDoLoading(true))
   ```

Answer (score 4):

First off, I recommend you reconsider the design of your "asynchronous event".

It is true that you can use a return value of `Task`, but it's more natural for C# event handlers to return `void`. In particular, if you have multiple subscriptions, the `Task` returned from `handler(this, ...)` is only the return value of *one* of the event handlers. To properly wait for all async events to complete, you'd need to use `Delegate.GetInvocationList` with `Task.WhenAll` when you raise the event.

Since you're already on the WinRT platform, I recommend you use "deferrals". This is the solution chosen by the WinRT team for asynchronous events, so it should be familiar to consumers of your class.

Unfortunately, the WinRT team did not include the deferral infrastructure in the .NET framework for WinRT. So I wrote a [blog post about async event handlers and how to build a deferral manager](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html).

Using a deferral, your event-raising code would look like this:

```
private Task OnDoLoading(bool mustLoadPreviousRunningState)
{
  var handler = this.DoLoading;
  if (handler == null)
    return;

  var args = new DoLoadingEventArgs(this, mustLoadPreviousRunningState);
  handler(args);
  return args.WaitForDeferralsAsync();
}

private Task PerformLoadingActionAsync()
{
  TaskFactory uiFactory = new TaskFactory(_uiScheduler);

  // Trigger event on the UI thread.
  var eventHandlerTask = uiFactory.StartNew(() => OnDoLoading(_mustLoadPreviousRunningState)).Unwrap();

  Task commandTask = Task.Run(() => this.ExecuteCommand());
  return Task.WhenAll(eventHandlerTask, commandTask);
}
```

So that's my recommendation for a solution. The benefits of a deferral are that it enables both synchronous and asynchronous handlers, it's a technique already familiar to WinRT developers, and it correctly handles multiple subscribers without additional code.

Now, as to why the original code doesn't work, you can think this through by paying careful attention to all the types in your code and identifying what each task represents. Keep in mind the following important points:

- `Task<T>` derives from `Task`. This means `Task<Task>` will convert down to `Task` without any warnings.
- `StartNew` is not `async`-aware so it behaves differently than `Task.Run`. See Stephen Toub's [excellent blog post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Your `OnDoLoading` method will return a `Task` representing the completion of the *last* event handler. Any `Task`s from other event handlers are ignored (as I mention above, you should use `Delegate.GetInvocationList` or deferrals to properly support multiple asynchronous handlers).

Now let's look at `PerformLoadingActionAsync`:

```
Task evenHandlerTask = await uiFactory.StartNew(async () => await this.OnDoLoading(_mustLoadPreviousRunningState));
```

There's a lot going on in this statement. It's semantically equivalent to this (slightly simpler) line of code:

```
Task evenHandlerTask = await uiFactory.StartNew(() => OnDoLoading(_mustLoadPreviousRunningState));
```

OK, so we are queueing up `OnDoLoading` to the UI thread. The return type of `OnDoLoading` is `Task`, so the return type of `StartNew` is `Task<Task>`. [Stephen Toub's blog goes into the details of this kind of wrapping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx), but you can think of it like this: the "outer" task represents the *start* of the asynchronous `OnDoLoading` method (up until it has to yield at an `await`), and the "inner" task represents the *completion* of the asynchronous `OnDoLoading` method.

Next, we `await` the result of `StartNew`. This unwraps the "outer" task and we get a `Task` that represents the completion of `OnDoLoading` stored in `evenHandlerTask`.

```
return Task.WhenAll(evenHandlerTask, commandTask);
```

Now you're returning a `Task` that represents when both `commandTask` and `evenHandlerTask` have completed. However, you're in an `async` method, so your actual return type is `Task<Task>` - and it's the inner task that represents what you want. I think what you meant to do was:

```
await Task.WhenAll(evenHandlerTask, commandTask);
```

Which would give you a return type of `Task`, representing the full completion.

If you look at how it's called:

```
this.PerformLoadingActionAsync().ContinueWith(...)
```

`ContinueWith` is acting on the *outer* `Task` in the original code, when you really wanted it to act on the *inner* `Task`.