# Triggering events from async/await functions in the right order

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, asynchronous, async-await

I have problems ensuring the order of events in my asynchronous task. The class from which other async tasks inherit has the following functions and takes the **EventHandlers (ExecutionProgress, ExecutionStarted, ExecutionCompleted)** in the constructor arguments:

```
public abstract Task Operation(IProgress<EventArgs> progress);

public virtual void Execute()
{
    ExecuteAsync()
}

private void ReportProgress(EventArgs args)
{
    if(ExecutionProgress != null) ExecutionProgress(this, args);
}
private async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    if(ExecutionStarted != null) ExecutionStarted(this, EventArgs.Empty)
    await Operation(new Progress<EventArgs>(ReportProgress));
    if(ExecutionCompleted != null) ExecutionCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty)

}
```

Now in one of my classes, that inherits from asynchronous tasks, i override Operation with the following:

```
public override async Task Operation(IProgress<EventArgs> progress)
{
    // run the synchronous function in another thread
    JobResults results = await Task.Run(() => worker.DoYourJob()); 
    progress.Report(results);
}
```

Running this code often, but not always, results in **NullReference Exception** in the **ExecutionCompleted** event handler when trying to access the **JobResults**. This is because **ExecutionProgress** event which writes the member variable usually gets fired after **ExecutionCompleted** for whatever reason. I think the standard says nothing about event ordering, but I'm looking for a nice solution to ensure deterministic ordering here.  **I want to fire ExecutionCompleted only after all ExecutionProgress events have been handled.**

What would be a nice looking solution here? Is there any way to **await** until all progress reporting events have been handled.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can see the whole picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The events are all *fired* in order.  If your event *handlers* are asynchronous, which seems to be the case, then the code firing the events is going to continue executing as soon as it *starts* the event handlers, not when they *complete*.

If the code firing the events needs to not continue on until all of the handlers have finished, then you need to restructure this class such that the event handlers have some means of indicating to this class when they're done.  There are any number of ways to do this, from passing a parameter in the event that allows handlers to tell it when they're done, or to having the signature of the event handlers return a `Task` rather than being `void` (you'll need to `await` those tasks when firing the event).

Comment: Note that `Task`-returning event handlers will require some work to make them work properly, since directly invoking the delegate will only return a `Task` from one of the subscribers.

Comment: I think the events firing in order is just a current implementation detail and should not be relied on in the future. svick, can you elaborate on how to implement it for multiple subscribers? I feel like returning a Task is the way to go here.

Comment: @ollo You can use `GetInvocationList()` for that. For more details, see the code snippet in point 1 of [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16419916/41071).